# SELECT MIN value with GROUP BY and INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I have a query pulling data from 4 different tables;

```
SELECT cd.name, tt.card_number, tt.deck_count, tcg.url, MIN(tcgp.marketPrice) as 'price'
FROM card_occurrences tt
INNER JOIN card_database cd ON tt.card_number = cd.id
INNER JOIN tcgplayer_cards tcg ON cd.name = tcg.name
INNER JOIN tcgplayer_set_prices tcgp ON tcgp.productId = tcg.productID
GROUP BY tt.card_number
ORDER BY tt.deck_count DESC LIMIT 100
```

However, the `tcg.url` is wrong and I know it's a result of using `MIN(tcgp.marketPrice)` with `GROUP BY`.

If I exclude the `MIN` and `GROUP BY then I get the ungrouped results like so:
[image]

However, when I do `MIN` with `GROUP BY` then I am correctly getting the lowest price but the URL is wrong. It's getting the first one found.
[image]

I think I need to use another JOIN statement (or maybe a subquery?) but I'm not entirely sure. Some prodding in the right direction is welcome!

Comment: First of all, that's the reason why you should never disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in your mysql config. You will mostly get not wanted results if you only group by one column and selecting other ones. To get the wanted result I would use a sub select fetching all minimum values first and then add the other columns.

Comment: If you assume that `MIN()` function will return corresponding value in all other columns, that's incorrect. If you're using MySQL version that supports window function (v8+), then you can try using `ROW_NUMBER()` function with your desired sorting (of the row number) then filter it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL v8+ (or MariaDB 10.2+), then I think you should try using `ROW_NUMBER()`. Consider this example:

```
SELECT cd.name, tt.card_number, tt.deck_count, tcg.url, tcgp.marketPrice as 'price',
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cd.name, tt.card_number ORDER BY tcgp.marketPrice) rn
FROM card_occurrences tt
INNER JOIN card_database cd ON tt.card_number = cd.id
INNER JOIN tcgplayer_cards tcg ON cd.name = tcg.name
INNER JOIN tcgplayer_set_prices tcgp ON tcgp.productId = tcg.productID;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cd.name, tt.card_number ORDER BY tcgp.marketPrice) rn` function is assigning row number to the row value based on `tcgp.marketPrice` ascending while retaining the corresponding column value for the row.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=882e7bc776a7e4e6bc3491e357f2973a)